# Adding <tr> from repeater's ItemDataBound Event

Tags: asp.net

My repeater's templates generate a table, where each item is a table row.
When a very very specific condition is met (itemdata), I want to add an additional row to the table from this event.

How can I do that?

```
protected void rptData_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
         e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {

        bool tmp = bool.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "somedata").ToString());
        if (!tmp && e.Item.ItemIndex != 0)
        {
            //Add row after this item
        }

   }
}
```

I can use e.Item.Controls.Add() and add TableRow but for that I need to locate a table right?
How can I solve that?

Answer (score 6):

I would put in the control in the repeater item template, set its visibility to hidden & only in that case, I will show it...

Like:

```
<asp:Repeater ...>

..

<ItemTemplate>

 <tr>
   <td>...</td>
 </tr>
 <tr runat="server" id="tr_condition" Visible="false">
  <td> Show only in specific condition </td>
 </tr>
```

Then in the ItemDataBound event:

```
var tr_condition = e.Item.FindControl("tr_condition") as HtmlTableRow;
tr_condition.Visible = myCondition;
```

where myCondition is a flag which gets sets on the specific condition

HTH

Comment: yes, but those controls will be available for all items in control tree even if they are not visible! It's not efficient.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see if this is an actual efficiency concern?

Comment: Agree with Charlie and Jason; premature optimization is the root of all evil, and toggling visibility of controls in repeaters is more or less a standard ASP.NET practice.

Comment: @MisterZimbu, even if the need control is toggled once per 30 items?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to include the row in the template code, and set the Visible property based on your 'tmp' variable. The you don't need to 'add' it - it is already there.

Edit: another idea - insert your extra row using a <%# %> data binding block. To do this, you need to generate the `<tr><td>..` code as a atring in your ItemDataBound event. Use a protected string variable - like this:

```
protected string _extraRowHtml;
```

in ItemDataBound:

```
_extraRowHtml = tmp ? "<tr><td>  -- generated content -- </td></tr>" : string.Empty;
```

in ItemTemplate:

```
<tr><td> -- regular row content --</td></tr>
<%# _extraRowHtml %>
```

Comment: please see my coment to Sunny's answer

Comment: these rows will not be rendered to the browser, if that is what you are worried about.

Comment: I know that, I am just worried about the control tree... many unnecessary controls...

Comment: I have problems with that, the line is generated in a wrong location.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the line is generated in a wrong location'? Is the row out of sequence? Is it missing from the table? Have you done a 'view source' to see what the generated html looks like?